# RC filter falloff

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis

I see a lot of examples saying that the falloff of a single pole RC circuit is -6dB/octave or -20/decade. I can see that thre frequency response of an RC lowpass filter shows this, but is there any mathematical prove that why it is -6dB/octave?

Maybe it is easy and I am just over complicating it !!

If Vout/Vin = R/[R^2 + (1/w^2*c^2)]^0.5, then is there some calculation that shows when w becomes (2w), then it Vout/Vin will be lower by about 6dB?

Comment: Never mind. I found the simplest explanation here at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-off

Comment: That's too complex for me LOL (see below)

Answer (score 3):

The output/input relationship for a low pass RC is: -

\$\dfrac{1}{1 + j\omega RC}\$

And once you get significantly past the 3dB threshold it tends to become this: -

\$\dfrac{1}{j\omega RC}\$

In other words a doubling of frequency (\$\omega\$) means a halving of output amplitude and of course doubling the frequency is an increase of 1 octave and a halving of amplitude is a 6dB attenuation therefore it's 6dB per octave.

Answer (score 0):

The roll-off is the consequence of how a fucntion of the form \$\frac{1}{1 + s}\$ behaves as the frequency rises. \$s\$ is a complex variable, and the frequency domain is along the positive imaginary axis, in other words we substitute \$s = j\omega\$ to obtain \$\frac{1}{1 + i\omega}\$, and considering positive values of \$\omega\$.

The amplitude is the modulus: \$\left|\frac{1}{1 + j\omega}\right|\$, and the decibels are 20 times the base 10 log of that.

The modulus of a complex value is the square root of the product of it and its complex conjugate: \$|z| = \sqrt{z\bar z}\$. Thus:

$$\left|\frac{1}{1 + i\omega}\right| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1 + j\omega\right)\left(1 - j\omega\right)}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + w^2}}$$

For large values of \$\omega\$, that just reduces to approximately \$\displaystyle\frac{1}{w}\$, since the inside of the square root reduces to approximately \$\displaystyle\frac{1}{w^2}\$.

Of course, \$\displaystyle\frac{1}{w}\$ cuts in half with each doubling of frequency, which is approximately a -6db drop.

So it all boils down to the rate of shrinkage of an n-degree polynomial as the independent variable grows large. First order is \$1/x\$: amplitude cuts in half every octave, thus -6db. Second order is \$1/x^2\$: amplitude cuts four-fold every octave, thus -12dB.

"Order" is the order of the polynomial in the denominator. An n-order polynomial in the denominator gives rise to n poles, so that's where we get "one pole filter", "two pole", etc.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there any mathematical prove that why it is -6dB/octave?

For voltage ratios in dB, we have:

$$(\frac{V_o}{V_i})_{db} = 20\log\frac{V_o}{V_i}$$

Now, consider the function

$$f(\omega) = 20\log\frac{1}{\omega}$$

When \$\omega\$ is *doubled*, \$f(\omega)\$ decreases by

$$20\log\frac{1}{2} = -6dB$$

Thus, we conclude that if the frequency response of a filter is inversely proportional to frequency, the response decreases at the rate of \$-6dB\$ per octave.

Now, for a 1st order low-pass filter, we have

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{1}{1 + j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}$$

For \$\omega\$ *much* larger than  \$\omega_0\$, we have

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} \approx \frac{1}{j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}} \propto \frac{1}{\omega}$$

Thus, well above the corner frequency, the frequency response is inversely proportional to frequency as required for a \$-6dB\$ roll-off.